# Table with rounded corners?

Tags: tables, examples

[image]

This table I can create with this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Team sheet} \\
  \hline
  GK & Paul Robinson \\
  LB & Lucus Radebe \\
  DC & Michael Duberry \\
  DC & Dominic Matteo \\
  RB & Didier Domi \\
  MC & David Batty \\
  MC & Eirik Bakke \\
  MC & Jody Morris \\
  FW & Jamie McMaster \\
  ST & Alan Smith \\
  ST & Mark Viduka \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But is there a possibility to use rounded corners? I'm talking about the 4 main corners and not the corners of each cell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a TikZ node with `inner sep=0pt` that holds the table, and then draw a rectangle around it.

**Update:** You can enclose this TikZ/tabular construct in a table environment to add a table caption and label to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table with rounded corners}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
  \hline
  GK & Paul Robinson \\
  LB & Lucus Radebe \\
  DC & Michael Duberry \\
  DC & Dominic Matteo \\
  RB & Didier Domi \\
  MC & David Batty \\
  MC & Eirik Bakke \\
  MC & Jody Morris \\
  FW & Jamie McMaster \\
  ST & Alan Smith \\
  ST & Mark Viduka \\
\end{tabular}
};
\draw [rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab1} can be referenced like any other.
\end{document}
```

[image: table with TikZ rounded corners, caption and label]

Comment: Oh wow, what a staccato of TikZ solutions here. Interesting to see the variation in the details of the approaches, though.

Comment: But yours is the simplest. So +1 for that.

Comment: @Jake Thanks that works, but were can i put the label and caption?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: You just enclose the whole stuff in a `table` environment, like you would with a normal table. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Captions above tables are better set up with the [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

Comment: @Thorsten: Good point, thank you! I've changed my answer.

Comment: @Jake I'm also using the capture package right now also for centering. One issues is still open. My table is very width. How can I force it into page width.. by linebreaks in the table text.

Answer (score 13):

All (I think?) the previous solutions don't work all that well in combination with coloured cell backgrounds:  the backgrounds will stick out over the prettily rounded corners.

The solution is to apply clipping.  And the difficulty with that is that the clipping path needs to be set before the table is drawn.  A.f.a.I.k., the only way of achieving this is saving the whole table into a box first, then setting the clipping path accordingly.  Just adding `clip` to the TikZ `node` didn't do it for me at least.

Since this amounts to quite a bit of boilerplate around the table, you could put the whole thing into an environment, and use the `environ` package to capture the table content conveniently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{named}{ForestGreen}

\NewEnviron{rndtable}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%
  \rowcolors{2}{tablecolor!20}{tablecolor!40}%
  \savebox{\tablebox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
      \BODY%
    \end{tabular}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip[rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
      \node at (0,-\dp\tablebox) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\tablebox}};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{rndtable}{l|l}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{tablecolor}\color{white} Team sheet} \\ \hline
    GK & Paul Robinson \\
    LB & Lucus Radebe \\
    DC & Michael Duberry \\
    DC & Dominic Matteo \\
    RB & Didier Domi \\
    MC & David Batty \\
    MC & Eirik Bakke \\
    MC & Jody Morris \\
    FW & Jamie McMaster \\
    ST & Alan Smith \\
    ST & Mark Viduka \\
  \end{rndtable}

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67736/3235 ;)

Comment: @percusse ah, a TikZ matrix, not bad!  Maybe mine is more convenient if you already have your table code with all the conventional colortbl/array/multicolumn markup?

Comment: Wow! @mabartibin that is good. Just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 12):

[tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) includes options tabularx and `tabularx*` which can draw framed tables with rounded corners.

The main problem will be to decide table width. All `tcolorboxes` use `\linewidth` as default horizontal box size, like`tabularx` and `tabularx*`. Therefore, tables narrower than `\linewidth` need to use manually calculated `width`s.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table with rounded corners}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{black!30}{white}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, width=.5\linewidth, tabularx={>{\centering\arraybackslash}l|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}, title={Team sheet}]
  GK & Paul Robinson \\
  LB & Lucus Radebe \\
  DC & Michael Duberry \\
  DC & Dominic Matteo \\
  RB & Didier Domi \\
  MC & David Batty \\
  MC & Eirik Bakke \\
  MC & Jody Morris \\
  FW & Jamie McMaster \\
  ST & Alan Smith \\
  ST & Mark Viduka \\
\end{tcolorbox}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab1} can be referenced like any other.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One of a nice suggestion...

Answer (score 7):

You could do this by putting the table into a [tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) node and framing that node with a rectangle that has rounded corners. See code below for some inspiration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tbl) {%
      \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\ \hline
        GK & Paul Robinson \\
        LB & Lucus Radebe \\
        DC & Michael Duberry \\
        DC & Dominic Matteo \\
        RB & Didier Domi \\
        MC & David Batty \\
        MC & Eirik Bakke \\
        MC & Jody Morris \\
        FW & Jamie McMaster \\
        ST & Alan Smith \\
        ST & Mark Viduka \\
      \end{tabular}
    };
      \draw[rounded corners] ($(tbl.north west)+(0.14,-0.14)$) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)+(-0.14,0.14)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: The result of the above code]

Answer (score 7):

you can do it with tikz fit library

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (tab){%
 \begin{tabular}{l|l}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
  \hline
  GK & Paul Robinson \\
  LB & Lucus Radebe \\
  DC & Michael Duberry \\
  DC & Dominic Matteo \\
  RB & Didier Domi \\
  MC & David Batty \\
  MC & Eirik Bakke \\
  MC & Jody Morris \\
  FW & Jamie McMaster \\
  ST & Alan Smith \\
  ST & Mark Viduka \\
\end{tabular}
};
\node[draw=red, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners=3pt, line width=2pt,
fit=(tab.north west) (tab.north east) (tab.south east) (tab.south west)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: about 30sec too late :) and a slightly different approach

Comment: Hmm. I always forget this `inner sep` option.

Comment: AFAIK you can just say `fit=(tab)` here. TikZ then automatically takes the `(tab.north west) (tab.north east) (tab.south east) (tab.south west)` coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcS}[hvlines, rounded-corners, rules/color=gray!60]
\CodeBefore
   \rowcolor{gray!60}{1}
   \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
\Body
   \RowStyle[bold]{}
    Town & Correspondant & {Value} \\
   Paris & Peter & 1.23 \\
   London & Helena & 23.23\\
   Madrid & Georges &12.5 \\
   Moscou & Henry & 4.77 \\
   Tokyo & Selena & 85.3 \\
   Lima & Victoria & 13.2 \\
   Cap Town & Alexandra & 6 \\
   Chicago & Vladimier & 1.34
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Simple and nice suggestion

Answer (score 6):

In OpTeX, you can use `\inoval{\table{...}}`:

```
\inoval[\fcolor=\relax \lcolor=\Black] {\table{l|l}{
  GK & Paul Robinson \cr
  LB & Lucus Radebe \cr
  DC & Michael Duberry \cr
  DC & Dominic Matteo \cr
  RB & Didier Domi \cr
  MC & David Batty \cr
  MC & Eirik Bakke \cr
  MC & Jody Morris \cr
  FW & Jamie McMaster \cr
  ST & Alan Smith \cr
  ST & Mark Viduka \cr
}}

\bye
```