# How to Create Comparison Tables in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, formatting

I am a new user (both to LaTeX & this forum).

I want to create a Comparison Table for an Article (like the one shown here):

[image]

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome! I think for such tables you need `tikz` or `pstricks`. Examples for tikz / pgfplosttable can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28087/example-of-fancy-table-using-tikz-package

Comment: @billjoy It would be useful to know which part of the table you are struggling with. Marco has already linked to a question about appearance: is that what you are after?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, I am trying to prepare a table with a similar appearance as in the link provided by Macro. Thanks.

Comment: I thought that making at least a perfectly rectangular table as above might be trivial with TiKZ, but it turns out to be annoyingly difficult to find a simple means of controlling the color of the first column while specifying the colors of the even/odd rows. I would appreciate a sketch of how one might make such tables as an illustrative exercise.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if we could have a live example for this problem.

Answer (score 28):

I swear somebody said TikZ!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip node (m) [matrix,matrix of nodes,
fill=black!20,inner sep=0pt,
nodes in empty cells,
nodes={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2.6cm,anchor=center,outer sep=0,font=\sffamily},
row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black,text=white}},
column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray,text=white,align=right,text width=2.5cm,text depth=0.5ex}},
column 2/.style={text width=4cm,align=center,every even row/.style={nodes={fill=white}}},
column 3/.style={text width=3cm,align=center,every even row/.style={nodes={fill=white}},},
row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
prefix after command={[rounded corners=4mm] (m.north east) rectangle (m.south west)}
] {
                & Enterprise SAN                     & ioDrive \\
Form Factor     & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe \\
Interface       & FC-4                               & PCIe x4 \\
Drive Units     & 150$\times$15 RPM disks            & 2$\times$80gig\\
Data Protection & Mirroring                          & Mirroring\\
Power           & 33.372 kWh/yr                      & 114 kWh/yr\\
SPC-1 I0PS      & 24.998                             & 86.127\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhhh so close! Can you easily make the first column (inlcuding the first row) entirely grey?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I've deliberately left it out since I think row is better to group but see the edit.

Comment: Having now taken time to look at the solution, it's good to know that `every even row` can be put in a column specification. I see that we get around the non-uniformity of the first column by setting the row styles in the remaining columns; it's a good thing that there aren't many columns.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap It's just a matter of overwriting the keys since the order matters and the last one dominates. If there are more columns we don't follow this path but make another strategy. It's more of an art rather than a technique. The source code also helps to see what is preceding over the rest.

Comment: @percusse I convert in 4 rows x 4 columns but it is not working

Answer (score 14):

[`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) includes a `tabularx` option which can be used to obtain rounded corners framed tabulars.

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{black!30}{white}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, notitle, clip upper, fontupper=\sffamily,%
    tabularx={>{\cellcolor[gray]{.5}\color{white}}r%
              >{\centering\arraybackslash}X%
              >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}]
  &\cellcolor{black!80}\color{white}Enterprise SAN &\cellcolor{black!80}\color{white}ioDrive \\
Form Factor     & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe \\
Interface       & FC-4                               & PCIe x4 \\
Drive Units     & 150$\times$15 RPM disks            & 2$\times$80gig\\
Data Protection & Mirroring                          & Mirroring\\
Power           & 33.372 kWh/yr                      & 114 kWh/yr\\
SPC-1 I0PS      & 24.998                             & 86.127
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Above code I convert in 4 rows x 4 columns but it is not working.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: Instead of asking in a comment it's better to do a new question with reference to this one. In any case unless you give us more information nobody could help. It's like: I've a problem, can you solve it?

Answer (score 13):

If you can live without the rounded corners, you can do something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[2]{white .. black!20}

\sffamily\footnotesize
\tabulinesep=6pt
\begin{tabu}{|>{\cellcolor{black!60}\color{white}}r|X[cm]|X[cm]|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80}\strut  & \color{white}Enterprise SAN & \color{white}ioDrive \\
Form Factor & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe \\
Interface & FC-4 & PCIe x4 \\
Drive Units & 150$\times$15 RPM disks & 2$\times$80gig\\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Rounded corners will probably need some TikZ magic, I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: I suspect you could do something with transparencies in PGF, to make a rectangle with an ovoid cutaway.

Comment: @tohecz Right, I tried putting \color{white} in \everyrow but that caused a strange error. Cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}[rounded-corners]{>{\color{white}\bfseries}rcc}
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{black!80}{1-2,1-3}
  \columncolor[gray]{0.5}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{black!30}{}[cols={2,3}]
\Body
    \RowStyle{\color{white}\bfseries}
                    & Enterprise SAN                     & ioDrive \\
    Form Factor     & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe \\
    Interface       & FC-4                               & PCIe x4 \\
    Drive Units     & 150$\times$15 RPM disks            & 2$\times$80gig\\
    Data Protection & Mirroring                          & Mirroring\\
    Power           & 33.372 kWh/yr                      & 114 kWh/yr\\
    SPC-1 I0PS      & 24.998                             & 86.127
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [rounded corners,thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]