# Adding vertical rule into tabu

Tags: tables, rules, tabu

Community, :)

I know it might sound like some noobish' question, but I have some trouble adding the last vertical rule into my tabu. I've retrieved the code from here: [How to Create Comparison Tables in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex)

I am using the code from user mrf, without using the TikZ package. I extended his example with more columns. So my code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\taburowcolors[2]{white .. black!20}
\sffamily\footnotesize
\tabulinesep=6pt
\begin{tabu}{|>{\cellcolor{black!60}\color{white}}r | X[cm] | X[cm]| X[cm] | X[cm] |}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80}\strut  & \color{white}Enterprise SAN & \color{white}ioDrive &      \color{white}test & \color{white}test2\\
Form Factor & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe & test & test2\\
Interface & FC-4 & PCIe x4 & test & test2\\
Drive Units & 150$\times$15 RPM disks & 2$\times$80gig & test & test2\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Test.}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
```

The problem is as soon as I extend the example from the link, there is a vertical rule missing in the table:

[image: Screenshot]

.. and I just cant find out why. If I define the beginning like this:

```
\begin{tabu}{|>{\cellcolor{black!60}\color{white}}r | X[cm] | X[cm]| X[cm] | X[cm] }
```

(Notice the missing `|` at the end) The line appears but therefore the vertical rule at the end of the table is missing. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**: KarlKoeller showed me that TexMaker is showing me in the preview the screenshot above, but with Adobe Reader its the opposite: The missing vertical line is there, but the others are missing then...

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand which horizontal line is missing. I see a vertical line missing between "Enterprise SAN" and "ioDrive".

Comment: Ouch. Kinda embarrassing ;) I'll edit that ofc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I see no problems with it. Maybe a problem with your PDF viewer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @karlkoeller. Indeed, TexMaker is showing me something else than Adobe Reader. TexMaker screenshot is provided above, with Adobe I see the vertical line at the place where its missing on the screenshot, but now the other ones after "Enterprise SAN" are missing... So its exactly the opposite of what I see with TexMaker

Comment: With SumatraPDF I can see ALL the lines... Same with Adobe Reader (try to zoom in)

Comment: @karlkoeller could you summarize this as an answer instead of a comment? :) Just that I can accept yours as the answer. Indeed, if I zoom in with Adobe every line is shown at some point (300% zoom!). Never faced this issue, would have never figure that out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with the PDF viewer.

I get no problems with SumatraPDF, while with Adobe Reader I have to zoom in to see all the vertical lines.

One way to circumvent it, is to increase the thickness of the lines, e.g. issue

```
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
```

In this way you should be able to see all vertical lines with every PDF viewer.

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\taburowcolors[2]{white .. black!20}
\sffamily\footnotesize
\tabulinesep=6pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\begin{tabu}{|>{\cellcolor{black!60}\color{white}}r | X[cm] | X[cm]| X[cm] | X[cm] |}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80}\strut  & \color{white}Enterprise SAN & \color{white}ioDrive &      \color{white}test & \color{white}test2\\
Form Factor & Rack Applicance (40U $\times$ 20") & Low Profile PCIe & test & test2\\
Interface & FC-4 & PCIe x4 & test & test2\\
Drive Units & 150$\times$15 RPM disks & 2$\times$80gig & test & test2\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Test.}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output (SumatraPDF):

[image]

Comment: Great, my bachelor thesis is saved - thanks. ;)

Comment: @guestFromOutside You're welcome. Note that you can also upvote the answer, if you want.