# Missing lines when shading cells

Tags: tables, colortbl

I cannot figure out why lines are not being showed on the shaded columns. Can I get a little help finding what is wrong?

[image: There should be lines on the shaded columns]

EDIT: The MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage {setspace} \doublespacing 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}    %for shading*
\usepackage{pifont}    %for pointing hand
\usepackage{arydshln}    %for dashed lines
\begin{document}

\begin{center} \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.2}
\scalebox{1}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{|rrl||c|c|c|} \hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c||}{kesaks} & CF & CS & F \\[0.5ex]
\hline \hline a. & \ding{43} & kesaks & $\ast$$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} \\
\hline b. & & gesaks & $\ast$$\ast$$\ast$! & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$ \\
\hline c. & & gezaks & $\ast$$\ast$$\ast$!$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$$\ast$ \\
\hline d. & & gezags & $\ast$$\ast$$\ast$!$\ast$$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$$\ast$$\ast$ \\
\hline  e. & & gezagz & $\ast$$\ast$$\ast$!$\ast$$\ast$$\ast$ & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray}$\ast$$\ast$$\ast$$\ast$$\ast$ \\
\hline \end{tabular}} \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1} \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect the lines are there, just _behind_ the shading.  It would be helpful if you made your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reprodcues the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: usually it's an artefact of your viewer, do the lines appear if you zoom in or out, or use a different viewer?

Comment: Oh, my god! That's right. On Adobe Reader and on the preview of textudio, it isn't possible to see the lines, but on Preview it is. Thank you!

Comment: Some possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53253/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149672/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150343/