# Table with alternating row colours and rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am trying to create a table with alternating row colours *and* rounded corners.

I combined two answers so far to achieve this:

- Thorsten Donnig's answer [about alternating row colours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/32206).
- Jake's answer [about adding rounded corners to a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10228/32206).

This works great in general, but the problem is that the alternating row colours method fills a proper square, not a rounded one, and the row colour "leaks" outside the table border. See the top left and bottom left corners of the image below.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Maybe by using the named `tikz` node to clip everything outside it?

## Issue:

[image: Issue]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,10pt,table]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{tablerow1}{RGB}{225,217,205}
\definecolor{tablerow2}{RGB}{236,229,221}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{tablerow1}{tablerow2}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (thetable) [inner sep=0pt] {
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}
      \arrayrulecolor{white}
      \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text. \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text.
    \end{tabularx}
  };
  \draw [rounded corners=.5em] (thetable.north west) rectangle (thetable.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex/67736#67736?

Comment: It might be a simplified version of the problem in that question? (Because it doesn't involve the first-column-out-of-pattern problem.) But given the comments on the accepted answer there, I wonder if a different solution might be preferable here.

Comment: @percusse Looks similar, but in my defence, there is no way I could have found that through searching. `:-)` Seems like I don't need something that complicated - all I need is to discard everything outside the node that draws the rounded rectangle. Plus, I'd prefer to stick with `tabularx` instead of `tikz`'s `matrix`.

Comment: You can put your table and clip that too. I meant the clipping part by the duplicate anyway :)

Comment: maybe the `tcolorbox` package?

Comment: @cmhughes I already have the answer I want (just a simple clip command!), but I'd be interested in alternatives and I'm sure other people would be too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `rounded corners=.5em` as a option for the whole `tikzpicture` and use `clip` as  node option. If you want to change the `line width` you have to set the new value also as an option of the `tikzpicture`.

Note that the `line width` also influences the table width if the table including the border should fit `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,table]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{tablerow1}{RGB}{225,217,205}
\definecolor{tablerow2}{RGB}{236,229,221}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{tablerow1}{tablerow2}
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.1mm,rounded corners=.5em]
  \node(thetable) [clip,inner sep=.5\pgflinewidth] {
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\pgflinewidth\relax}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}
      \arrayrulecolor{white}
      \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text. \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text.
    \end{tabularx}
  };
  \draw ([xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.north west) 
    rectangle ([xshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the `even odd rule` to fill the area around the table:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,table]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{tablerow1}{RGB}{225,217,205}
\definecolor{tablerow2}{RGB}{236,229,221}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{tablerow1}{tablerow2}
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.1mm]
  \node (thetable) [inner sep=.5\pgflinewidth] {
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\pgflinewidth\relax}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}
      \arrayrulecolor{white}
      \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text. \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text.
    \end{tabularx}
  };
  \fill[white,even odd rule]
    (current bounding box.north west)rectangle(current bounding box.south east)
    {[rounded corners=.5em]([xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.north west) 
      rectangle ([xshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.south east)};
  \draw[rounded corners=.5em] ([xshift=.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.north west) 
    rectangle ([xshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth,yshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]thetable.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) This is much better than my answer.

Comment: Exactly the simple answer I had in mind! Thanks! Just to perfect this: do you know how I make it so the white background is not visible in the table when I use, for example, `line width=0.1mm` in the second node? The black border and clipped rounded rectangle do not merge seamlessly (especially at the corners).

Comment: Notice that, `clip` has no effect in the node options in the current state.

Comment: @sudosensei I have changed my answer. `line width` is now taken into account.

Comment: This is great – it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

If you just need a framed tabular, `tcolorbox` can help you (as cmhughes suggested).

It has a `tabularx` option which accepts a tabularx header definition and also accepts `colortbl` or `xcolor` commands for coloring cells, rows or columns.

`array`, `tabularx` and `xcolor` (or `colortbl`) must be loaded in addition to `tcolorbox`.

If `rowcolors` or `rowcolor` are used, it's convinient to include `clip upper` option in `tcolorbox` definition (look at figures below).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt,table]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\definecolor{tablerow1}{RGB}{225,217,205}
\definecolor{tablerow2}{RGB}{236,229,221}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{tablerow1}{tablerow2}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, notitle, clip upper, 
         tabularx={>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X%
                   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}]
     \arrayrulecolor{white}
     \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
     Some text. & Some text. \\ \hline
     Some text. & Some text.
  \end{tcolorbox}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `clip upper` option the result is:

[image]

*Update*

In case some `code` has to be applied before tabular starts, use option
`tabularx*={<code>}{<preamble>}` instead of `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt,table]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\definecolor{tablerow1}{RGB}{225,217,205}
\definecolor{tablerow2}{RGB}{236,229,221}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{tablerow1}{tablerow2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, notitle, clip upper,
       tabularx*={\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}}%
                 {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.4\hsize}X%
              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}]
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text. \\ \hline
      Some text. & Some text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I'm torn now! This looks lovely and incredibly elegant as well! May I ask what the equivalent of `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}` would be in this case? It doesn't seem to have any effect when I use it.

Comment: @sudosensei   All tabular changes can be applied with `tabularx*` option. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great. I had tried that, but I apparently I had forgotten to add a `%` after the first parameter, resulting in a spurious whitespace character (and compilation error). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.18). You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,10pt,table]{standalone}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[14,l]X[6,l]}[rounded-corners]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors[RGB]{1}{225,217,205}{236,229,221}
\Body
  \Block[rounded-corners,draw,transparent]{*-*}{}
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}
  Column 1 & Column 2 \\ \Hline[color=white]
  Some text. & Some text. \\ \Hline[color=white]
  Some text. & Some text.
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]