Helping making an illustration of data of tables with tikz
Im trying to make the following illustration in latex. Im trying to use tikz, but can't figure how to make all text be in one single cell, make the whole tabular smaller and getting the 2 cells to the left, but also having the data in the other cells.
The illustration:

I have tried the following code, but it's far away from the goal.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=1ex,
        text height=3ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=3em}
        },
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                text=black,
            }
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (first) [table,text width=6em]
{
 Mængde af 1'ere & 0 &1 & 2 & 3\\
 2 & [0,0,0] & [0,0,1] & D & E \\
     & G & H & J & K \\
     & B & C & D & E \\
     & G & H & J & K \\
};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Current output:


For the rounded corners, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10224/table-with-rounded-corners

You can use ordinary tabulars and put them into nodes with inner sep=0pt.
\node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt](A){%
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
  ...
  \end{tabular}%
};


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-stealth, shorten < = 4pt, shorten > = 4pt]
  \node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt](A){%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
      Mængde of 1'ere & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \hline
      \multirow{3}{*}{Binære tal}
      & $[0,0,0]$ & $[0,0,1]$ &$[0,1,1]$ & $[1,1,1]$ \\
      &           & $[0,1,0]$ &$[1,0,1]$ &           \\  
      &           & $[1,0,0]$ &$[1,1,0]$ &  
    \end{tabular}%
  };
  \node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt](B)[below=of A]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
      Mængde of 1'ere & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \hline
      \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{5em}{Sorterede\\Binære tal}}
      & $[0,0,0]$ & $[0,0,1]$ &$[0,1,1]$ & $[1,1,1]$ \\
      &           & $[0,0,1]$ &$[0,1,1]$ &           \\  
      &           & $[0,0,1]$ &$[0,1,1]$ &  
    \end{tabular}%
  };
  \node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt](C)[below=of B]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
      Mængde of 1'ere & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \hline
      \parbox{5em}{\strut Sorterede\\Binære tal\strut}
      & $[0,0,0]$ & $[0,0,1]$ &$[0,1,1]$ & $[1,1,1]$
    \end{tabular}%
  };
  \draw[->] (A) -- node[left]{Sorter listerne} (B);
  \draw[->] (B) -- node[left]{Duplikater fjernes} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thank you so much! Is there a document you could recommend, that teaches tikzpicture?

I primarily learned from the PGF manual, by looking at the many examples in this document, copying the code and then modifying it. And then searching for the required modifications (in the manual or at this site). And asking questions here. There is also a minimal introduction to TikZ.
